# Why I get an error when I try to upload a picture

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have error when i upload photo, name of photo shows up but not the picture. I dont know why the error occurs the script is at the end of body.

**Error message in browser**

```
new:181 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (new:181)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

**HTML code**

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Photos:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" id="fileImage" accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                class="mb-2"/>
                <img id="thumbnail" alt="Photos preview" th:src="@{/images/default-user.png}"
                class="img-fluid"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JQuery code**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#buttonCancel").on("click", function () {
            window.location = "[[@{/users}]]";
        });

        $("#fileImage").change(function () {
            fileSize = this.file[0].size;
            alert("File size: " + fileSize);

            // max 1MB
            if (fileSize > 1048576) {
                this.setCustomValidity("You must choose an image less than 1MB");
                this.reportValidity();
            } else {
                this.setCustomValidity("");
                showImageThumbnail(this);
            }
        });
    });

    function showImageThumbnail(fileInput) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#thumbnail").attr("src", e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe change `this.file[0]` to `this.files[0]` ?

Comment: please provide a codepen to debug with

Comment: @johnSmith yup, this indeed is the same issue. You should have provided the solution also for OP to debug. So, that we could not have done the same

Comment: @BilluBaziger why? There's enough code in the question to create a snippet. Asking people to create an off-site resource is a little needless.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree, However, there is enough code to use SO editor and put our answer.

Comment: @BobMaster: As suggested by other SO Members, it seems it is only a typo and you just need to follow john smith's comment. If you still face issues I am keeping a codepen.io link for you for the same.
https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/XWRaKLG?editors=1111

Cheers !!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Two things here:
You forget to declare the fileSize variable.
And it's

```
this.files[0]
```

So here's how you get your file size

```
let fileSize = this.files[0].size;
```

And a working example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('test')
    $("#buttonCancel").on("click", function () {
        window.location = "[[@{/users}]]";
    });

    $("#fileImage").change(function () {
        let fileSize = this.files[0].size;
        alert("File size: " + fileSize);

        // max 1MB
        if (fileSize > 1048576) {
            this.setCustomValidity("You must choose an image less than 1MB");
            this.reportValidity();
        } else {
            this.setCustomValidity("");
            showImageThumbnail(this);
        }
    });
});

function showImageThumbnail(fileInput) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#thumbnail").attr("src", e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but you should just vote to close questions caused by typos. Suggest the fix in a comment, if it hasn't already been done.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yeah, it's obviously not just a typo, when he assigned a variable without declaring it..

Comment: That's a corollary issue, as the code will still work without the explicit definition. The variable will just be declared at window level. The use of `file[0]` instead of `files[0]` is the typo which causes the console error, and prevents further execution.

Comment: @NICO Hi My friend. I feel we can consider it as a typo only :) I know it feels bad, however if a variable is not declared in JS, it is declared in global scope. So, that doesn't cause any trouble in this particular scenario.

Let's downvote to close it I guess :) But before closing it, This should be answered somewhere to mark it as duplicate. Otherwise, let's not close it at all. Let's keep our answers, they can be helpful to other's/

Comment: I'm not on a mission at all. I was trying to explain why your answer was downvoted to allay some of your frustration. The specific reason why typos should not be answered has been covered many times on meta. One example of that is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/519413